# GEE minimum reflectance composite based on specific band

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I want to create a minimum reflectance composite.

How do I create an `ee.Image` from an `ee.ImageCollection`, containing all bands of the orginal Collection where each Pixel is chosen by the temporal minimum of a specific band, for example `B10`?

```
var s2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2').filterBounds(small_tile);
s2 = s2.filterDate(start, end).select(['B7', 'B8', 'B8A', 'B10']);

//
comp = s2.reduce(/*?*/) //chose B7, B8, B8A pixels based from image where B10 is min in the collection for each pixel, also include B10 pixel in image.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use qualityMosaic, which will do what you're asking based on the maximum value in a band, and just invert the band you want to index on:

```
var result = s2.map(function(img) {
   var index = img.select("B10").multiply(-1).rename("index")
   return img.addBands(index)
}).qualityMosaic("index")
```